# How to add a new method to DataFrame type?

Tags: scala

Imagine I have this Scala function that operates upon a Spark dataframe:

```
class MyClass {
      def makeColumnNull(df: DataFrame, columnToMakeNull: String): DataFrame = {
        val colType = df.select(columnToMakeNull).schema.head.dataType
        df.withColumn(columnToMakeNull, lit(null).cast(colType))
      }
}
```

I call it like so:

```
val df = spark.range(0,10).toDF()
val df2 = MyClass.makeColumnNull(df, "id")
```

That works fine however it doesn't work in the same fluent manner as Spark's API. What I'd like to is rewrite my function in a way that enables me to do this:

```
val df2 = df.makeColumnNull("id")
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How is this related to Spark? Would anything change if you spoke about any other Scala object that you wanted to extend with an extra method?

Comment: Possibly not, but as a total Scala noob it helped me (and possibly others) to provide some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit classes is the way to go, I've used them to extend several spark classes. So you need this:

```
package com.mycompany.utils.spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

object DataFrameExtensions {

  implicit class DataFrameWrapper(df: DataFrame) {

    def makeColumnNull(columnToMakeNull: String): DataFrame = {
      val colType = df.select(columnToMakeNull).schema.head.dataType
      df.withColumn(columnToMakeNull, lit(null).cast(colType))
    }

  }
}
```

then you have to import `com.mycompany.utils.spark.DataFrameExtensions._` and you will able to invoke `makeColumnNull()` against any `DataFrame` object

Comment: What do you think about using `package object` for implicits?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski Coming from other languages, I find Scala package objects confusing... but I will try to understand them :)